# Fetching Only Unique Results From Sql Database

Tags: mysql, sql, distinct

Database Table

```
    ID      Post                Tags
    1       Range rover         range-rover,cars
    2       Lamborghini         lamborghini,cars
    3       Kawasaki            kawasaki,bikes
    4       Yamaha R1           yamaha,r1,bikes
```

I Want to Remove Duplicate Values from Result sql

What i Get When i fetch tags (tags are in ,) from Database

```
SELECT Tags from posts;
```

Resut:

```
range-rover,cars lamborghini,cars kawasaki,bikes yamaha,r1,bikes
```

What I Need is not to show same result again.

```
range-rover,cars lamborghini kawasaki,bikes yamaha,r1
```

Comment: You should make 2 more tables: intermediate (id_post, id_tag) and the tags table(id, name)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can split your text using tally table and `SUBSTRING_INDEX`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(t.tags, ',', n.n), ',', -1) AS val
FROM posts t 
CROSS JOIN 
(
   SELECT a.N + b.N * 10 + 1 n
     FROM 
    (SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) a
   ,(SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) b
) n
 WHERE n.n <= 1 + (LENGTH(t.tags) - LENGTH(REPLACE(t.tags, ',', '')))
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bab73/3/0)**</kbd>

If you need one row add `GROUP_CONCAT`:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(t.tags, ',', n.n), ',', -1)) AS val
...
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo2`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bab73/6/0)**</kbd>